# Powershell ISE to Notepad++

Tags: powershell, notepad++, powershell-ise

I've started using notepad++ to write powershell scripts but the colour syntax is not very intuitive, I've also been using Powershell ISE this whole time and I've gotten used to its colour theme.

Is there a way to import the Powershell ISE language colour theme into Notepad++ please?

Comment: Forgive the silly question but why would you use Notepad++ over the ISE? You lose other features like code execution and tab autocompletion.

Comment: @Matt Probably because of ridiculous bugs like how [Ctrl-X stops working](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/777187/ctrl-x-cut-keyboard-shortcut-stops-working-in-powershell-ise-after-a-while).

Comment: @Matt apparently im not the only one who's ISE console keeps hanging. Although ISE recovers the tabs nicely after the freeze i am getting used to this nuisance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something about adding PowerShell syntax support in the notepad++

1. [creating-a-user-defined-language-in-notepad](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/creating-a-user-defined-language-in-notepad)
2. [powershell-language-definitions-for-notepad](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway//powershell-language-definitions-for-notepad)

Comment: Thanks, I've got this implemented but its nothing like the Powershell ISE colours.

Comment: @ZeeDaim You'll have to modify the Notepad++ syntax definition to use colors the way you want.  It will never perfectly replicate Powershell ISE unless you pour a ton of time and effort into it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try **SynWrite** with PowerShell lexer, its lexer colors are configurable (dialog "Lexer styles") and lexer is configurable as well (all its rules, keywords...)